# How to create a rebar module that is not an Erlang OTP app?

Tags: erlang, rebar

Is it possible to use rebar to create a simple project module skeleton that is **not** based on an OTP application ? Overall I want to use that project structure to become a library for other rebar generated applications.

The structure should be as follows:

```
/myprojectlib 
     /src
     /ebin
     /deps
```

The idea is to use it on the **deps** section of a **rebar.config** file:

```
{ deps, [myprojectlib] }.
```

At the moment, because myprojectlib is not a rebar project (and an OTP app) the rebar compilation fails with the message that it cannot identify myprojectlib, even if it is in the /deps directory of the target folder. **I checked further and it appears that the deps of the rebar.config file only accepts other rebar projects, hence my need to create a simple rebar project which is not an OTP application.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Erlang libraries are apps. They are however called library apps.

You can create a sample library app with `rebar create-lib libid=myprojectlib`.